# Displaying all records before 90 days

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to display a list of donors who are available to donate blood. For this I'm calculating if their last donation date is before 90 days or not. Here is my query:

```
select *
from donar, donation
    donar.id=donation.donar_id
    and sex='female'
    and datediff(curdate(),donation_date) > 120
```

The problem is it displays donor's name perfectly but if a donor gave blood now it still shows his name in list beacuse he has a previous entry before 90 days. How can I solve this?

Comment: what is the field type for "donation_date" ?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but you probably mean "donor" and not "donar".

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a where in your example. Give this a shot... you need to look at the query from another angle... Based on your comments below, here is a simple way to get the males and females by different day limits.  You could probably do this without the UNION in  a single statement, but I think the union keeps the logic of the different days for men and women.

```
 SELECT * from donor 
   LEFT JOIN donation ON donor.id=donation.donor_id 
        AND donation.donation_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 120 day
 WHERE donation.donation_id IS NULL  
      AND donor.sex='female' 

 UNION   

 SELECT * from donor 
   LEFT JOIN donation ON donor.id=donation.donor_id 
        AND donation.donation_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 90 day
 WHERE donation.donation_id IS NULL  
      AND donor.sex='male'
```

Basically this query says "Give me all the people in the donar table, include info on those with donations withing 90 days, then only show those without donation details (AKA people who haven't donated in 90 days).

Comment: Actually I wrote from mobile by hand so I missed some words. Query was perfect bu problem was it displays donar even if she has a new donation after 120 days. I,m trying ur one ...

Comment: @dxenaretionx I thought your want anyone in the donor list who hasn't donated in 90 days.  Is it 90 or 120?  I'm assuming all people in your donor table have donated at least once.  If not some edits are needed.

Comment: @dxenaretionx "missed some words" sorry but how do you expect us to help you, wait till you are in fount of a real keyboard before posting.

Comment: Yes u r right It will display donar if he/she not donated for 90 (male) 120(female), if there is any 2nd entry which is less than 90,120 then list will not display his info

Comment: @dxenaretionx Ok, my query will do this for females.  You can run a second one and union it with the first for male vs.  female, see the edits to my answer.  You need to be clearer in you question as to what exactly the final result should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from donar 
       left join donation 
                 on ( donar.id=donation.donar_id )
       where (
               ( sex='female' and datediff(curdate(),donation_date) > 120) 
               or 
               ( sex='male' and datediff(curdate(),donation_date) > 90) 
             )
             or donation.id is null;
```